# Parameters for entrypoint component (webpack)

Tags: javascript, webpack, entry-point

my webpack config uses the main.jsx as entry component.

This does all work as such and I call it like this:

```html
<script src="./myApp.js"></script>
<script>
  new myApp({
    targetElem: document.querySelector('#order-form'),
    productData: ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']
  });
</script>
```

What I want to achieve is, to use parameters that I provide, namely **targetElem** and **productData**

The main.jsx looks like that and works perfectly:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import store from '../store';
import i18n from '../i18n';
import Start from './pages/start';

render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistSt ore(store)}>
      <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
        <Router>
          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Start} />
          </Switch>
        </Router>
      </I18nextProvider>
    </PersistGate>
  </Provider>, // Contextprovider does not work at the moment as they have an error there
  document.querySelector('#order-form')
);
```

If I change it to this, to use the parameters:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import { I18nextProvider } from 'react-i18next';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { persistStore } from 'redux-persist';
import { PersistGate } from 'redux-persist/integration/react';
import store from '../store';
import i18n from '../i18n';
import Start from './pages/start';

export default ({ productData, targetElem }) => {
  console.log(productData);
  render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistStore(store)}>
        <I18nextProvider i18n={i18n}>
          <Router>
            <Switch>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Start} />
            </Switch>
          </Router>
        </I18nextProvider>
      </PersistGate>
    </Provider>, // Contextprovider does not work at the moment as they have an error there
    targetElem
  );
};
```

The page stays white (and no errors in the console). I have seen that it is definitely somehow possible. How to do it ?

Comment: Is there specific reason why you would want to pass these parameters from the global scope?

Comment: @Trace yes, the react app needs to have the possibility to get parameters. If you have another idea how to do that, I would be interested to hear.

Answer (score 0):

What you seem to be wanting to pass as parameters is:

1) A static DOM element
2) Server data

1) It is usual for the DOM element to just be added in the `myApp.js`. This is just DOM crawling, there is no actual benefit if you put it in one script or the other.

2) Making a basic call after initial render in React can be performed from the React component itself:

- `componentDidMount` if you're using regular class components
- `useEffect(() => { // here }, []);` if you're using functional components with hooks
- Of course you can also dispatch an action if you use Redux or `useDispatch`.

Just to say that you don't need to pass these variables from the global scope.

You can use local state in your React component as well obviously with the `useState` hook.

Edit to your comment:

In that case you could have another React component that handles the user input, and pass it to the component, for example using Redux. Obviously you can always pass data via the DOM using data-attributes for example like it was done in the old days, but this is not so common anymore.
I used pregenerated json before and the way I handled this, was by using SSR and using Redux to hydrate the state in the store automatically:

https://redux.js.org/recipes/server-rendering#inject-initial-component-html-and-state

Anyhow, you can just fetch preloaded state from the window object.

Comment: I want to make it possible users to call the app by using new myApp() with parameters. A use case for that is a content management system where json is pregenerated and just passed as a parameter to the ReactJS app. What I also want to achieve is that a person can decide in which DOM-element the react app should be rendered. Therefor your answer is useless for me, I know how to use componentDidMount() and useEffect() but I need targetElem before that, as I want to render the whole reactjs app into this element.

Comment: But how did you get your json to the point that you can hydrate it to redux ? I don't want to read it out of the HTML.

Comment: @Gutelaunetyp In the example provided by Redux, you fetch it from the window object and then pass it to the Redux store on creation of the store. As they recommended it in the docs this way, I went with it, and I don't see a reason why this would be a problem. Using the window object (global scope) is in itself only bad for possible name collisions (and nullpointers when used in multiple places), which is why in the old days they would namespace the window object. But here all your JS logic is bundled with webpack in ES6 modules, so I don't see how it matters as it's just bootstrap.